# How to match a pattern with String variable in Java

Tags: java, regex, user-input

I have a code that is supposed to get an input, get the last 2 letters from the first input, then match the second input with the last two letters (ex. glam, slam). The issue is that it keeps going to the else statement rather than the if statement. Is there an issue with how the pattern is constructed?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatchyPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the first word: ");
        String fw;
        fw = s.nextLine();
        String lastTwo = fw.substring(fw.length() - 2);
        char[] sub = lastTwo.toCharArray();
        var p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1,2}" + sub + "]");
        
        
        System.out.print("Enter the second word: ");
        String sw;
        sw = s.nextLine();
        
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sw);
        
        if (m.matches()){
            System.out.println(fw + " rhymes with " + sw);
        }else{
        System.out.println("I'm not sure! Sorry!");
        }

    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: did you print `p` to see what's inside ? Also I don't see the opening bracket that you close (in the pattern

Comment: Try use `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1,2}" + lastTwo);`

Comment: I included the closing bracket because without it, I'm getting an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 23
[a-zA-Z]{1,2}[C@6d03e736

Comment: can u explain why it doesnt work with the "sub" ?

It works now btw. Thanks

Comment: What would expect with `sub` ? Write the expectec pattern that it would build. Also see my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't understand what `[C@37f8bb67` (part after @ varies) is and you naivly tried to "close" the bracket. What you see is the default array [`toString`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array), that has no meaning in code at all

---

You may just padd the pattern with the 2 last char (as a string)

```
var p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{1,2}" + lastTwo);
```